# How to use Remote Desktop Client (RD Client) for accessing a Windows 10 Enterprise Guest OS?

Tags: windows-10, networking, remote-desktop

**Guest System**

Windows 10 Enterprise is installed as a Guest OS.

Its network connection type is NAT.

Microsoft Remote Desktop assistant is installed in Windows 10 Enterprise.

ipconfig of Guest OS says:

- IPv4: 192.168.232.139 and
- Default Gateway: 192.168.232.2

When I open Microsoft Remote Desktop assistant, it displays as

- PC Name: 192.168.232.139 and
- User name: Computer-name\user-name

**Host System**

ipconfig of Host OS says:

- IPv4: 192.168.0.105 and
- Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

**Problem**

Using RD Client App, I am trying to access Windows 10 Enterprise Guest OS on a Android Phone. Android Phone and laptop both are on the same network and connected with the same WIFI.

I accessed router page by 192.168.0.1 and found the IP assigned to the Android Phone is 192.168.0.103.

I used details in RD Client for connecting:
PC Name: 192.168.232.139 and
User name: Computer-name\user-name

It says, Error Code: 0x104

How can resolve this problem?

Comment: What hypervisor? Hyper-V?

Comment: VMWare Workstation Pro

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect to the guest machine if it's behind a NAT. [You need to configure a port forward or use a bridged connection instead of NAT](https://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/).

Answer (score 0):

This article [How To Enable Remote Desk­top or RDP in VMware](https://www.guidingtech.com/25191/remote-desktop-rdp-vmware/) might help you to configure the network settings correctly, so that you could remotely connect to the guest OS.

Comment: BTW: that is port forwarding (as already suggested)